# Get value from dictionary given a list of nested keys

Tags: python, python-2.x, recursion, hash-map

I would like to get a deeply-nested value, for example `{"a":{"b":{"c":"myValue"}}` by providing the keys to traverse. I tried chaining together .get() but that didn't work for cases where some of the keys were missing—in those cases, I want to get `None` instead.

Could this solution be improved?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

def nestedGet(d,p):
    if len(p) > 1:
        try:
            return nestedGet(d.get(p[0]),p[1:])
        except AttributeError:
            return None
    if len(p) == 1:
        try:
            return d.get(p[0])
        except AttributeError:
            return None

print nestedGet({"a":{"b":{"c":1}}},["a","b","c"]) #1
print nestedGet({"a":{"bar":{"c":1}}},["a","b","c"]) #None
```

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dpath

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something you'd like to implement, I would go for a simple loop instead of using recursion:

```
def nested_get(input_dict, nested_key):
    internal_dict_value = input_dict
    for k in nested_key:
        internal_dict_value = internal_dict_value.get(k, None)
        if internal_dict_value is None:
            return None
    return internal_dict_value

print(nested_get({"a":{"b":{"c":1}}},["a","b","c"])) #1
print(nested_get({"a":{"bar":{"c":1}}},["a","b","c"])) #None
```

Answer (score 9):

I like the following approach that makes use of [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). It generalizes nicely to other indexable sequences such as lists and tuples.

```
from functools import reduce
def get_nested_item(data, keys):
    return reduce(lambda seq, key: seq[key], keys, data)
```

This can be further simplified by direct access to the `__getitem__` method of the sequences, which leads to a noticeable increase in performance (I measured 20-35% for different test data):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem
def get_nested_item(data, keys):
    return reduce(getitem, keys, data)
```

Usage:

```
get_nested_item(data={"a":{"b":{"c":1}}}, keys=["a","b","c"]) # => 1
get_nested_item(data=[[[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]], keys=[0,1,2])    # => 30
get_nested_item(data={'a':0, 'b':[[1,2]]}, keys=['b',0,1])    # => 2
get_nested_item(data=some_sequence, keys=[])                  # => some_sequence
```

If one prefers soft failure for missing keys/indices, one can catch `KeyError` or `IndexError`.

```
def get_nested_item(data, keys):
    try:
        return reduce(getitem, keys, data)
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return None
```

Comment: Instead of using

`except (KeyError, IndexError):`

[LookupError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#LookupError) could be used. 

According to the documentation: "The base class for the exceptions that are raised when a key or index used on a mapping or sequence is invalid: IndexError, KeyError."

So it would be: `except LookupError:`

Answer (score 6):

If you were to solve it with a third-party package, like [`jsonpath-rw`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath-rw), the solution would be as simple as constructing the path by joining the keys with a dot and parsing the dictionary:

```
from jsonpath_rw import parse


def nested_get(d, path):
    result = parse(".".join(path)).find(d)
    return result[0].value if result else None
```

Some code style notes about your current approach:

- Python functions does not follow the camel case naming conventions, put an underscore between words - `nested_get()` instead of `nestedGet()`
- there should be extra spaces after the commas ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements))
- improve on variable naming, make them more descriptive - for instance, `p` can be named as `path`
- use `print()` *function* instead of a statement for Python3.x compatibility

Answer (score 6):

You can chain together `dict.get()` functions and use the optional `default` argument and specify an empty dict to return instead of `None` if the key doesn't exist. Except, let the last `.get()` return `None` if the key is not found.

If any of the keys to be traversed are missing, a empty dict is returned and the following `.get()`s in the chain will be called on the empty dict, which is fine., The final `.get()` in the chain will either return the value if all the keys exist or will return `None` as desired.

example 1:

```
input_dict = {"a":{"b":{"c":1}}} #1
input_dict.get("a", {}).get("b", {}).get("c") # 1
```

example 2:

```
input_dict = {"a":{"bar":{"c":1}}} #1
input_dict.get("a", {}).get("b", {}).get("c") # None
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a compact and versatile way to accomplish this without extra libraries:

```py
nest = {"a":{"b":{"c":"myValue"}}}

def getElementFromDict(dict, elementChain):
    for key in elementChain:
        dict = dict.get(key, {})
    return dict

getElementFromDict(nest,['a','b','c'])
```

yields `myvalue`

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: @TobySpeight It is very short and consise, but there is very definitely an observation there about verbosity and extra libraries.

Comment: I don't think so - the question code includes no libraries that aren't in this implementation.  It's just a code dump with some text added as a kind of justification.

Comment: @TobySpeight I reviewed the code and I'm actually using it as suggested here. Please read my entry statement and compare it to the other solutions.

Comment: Bear in mind that most of the other answers are very old, and not up to the standards expected of an answer in 2022.